# Generating and updating 8-bit gray-scale texture in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glteximage2d

For an OpenGL texture cache I need to initialize a large (≥ 2048x2048) texture and then frequently update little sections of it.

The following (pseudo-)code works:

```java
// Setup texture
int[] buffer = new int[2048*2048 / 4]; // Generate dummy buffer with 1 byte per pixel
int id = glGenTexture();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, 2048, 2048, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

// Perform update
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, width, height, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

But I find the totally unnecessary creation of a 4MB int-buffer a bit undesirable to say the least. So, I tried the following instead:

```java
// Setup texture
int id = glGenTexture();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, 0, 0, 2048, 2048, 0);
```

This gave me a GL_INVALID_OPERATION error, which I believe is caused by the fact that the frame-buffer does not contain an alpha value, so rather than just setting that to 1, the call fails.

Next attempt:

```java
// Setup texture
int id = glGenTexture();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, 0, 0, 2048, 2048, 0);
```

This works, but now my glTexSubImage2D call fails with GL_INVALID_OPERATION because it specifies GL_ALPHA instead of GL_LUMINANCE. So, I changed that as well to get:

```java
// Perform update
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, x, y, width, height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

And I changed my shader to read the value from the `r` rather than the `a` component.

This works on some devices, but on the iPhone 3GS, I still get the GL_INVALID_OPERATION error in the glTexSubImage2D call. Why? And how can I fix this? Is there some way, for example, to change the internal texture format? Or can I create some other framebuffer that does have an alpha component that I can use as the source for glCopyTexImage2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` can be `NULL` in your [`glTexImage2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) call if you just want to allocate an empty texture:

> `data` may be a null pointer.  In this case, texture memory is allocated to accommodate a texture of `width` and `height`.  You can then download subtextures to initialize this texture memory.  The image is undefined if the user tries to apply an uninitialized portion of the texture image to a primitive.

Comment: Wow! How did I miss THAT one??? AWESOME! That makes life so much easier, of course! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any idea, though, where that error on the iPhone 3GS might be coming from? Is this some bug? Or some special case that I am not seeing? If I initialize the texture with glTexImage2D and GL_LUMINANCE everything works, just clCopyTexImage2D doesn't seem to get along with GL_LUMINANCE...